# getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view) returns null

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, findviewbyid

I have seen some similar question about this but it was all for different reasons (I think).
The code I am using is taken from http://developer.android.com/training.
I am trying to build a simple contacts app according to the tutorial:
http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html
The part where I am getting the bug is **Set up the CursorAdapter for the ListView**.
This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
        mCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), 
                R.layout.contacts_list_item, null, FROM_COLUMNS, TO_COLUMN, 0);
        mContactsList.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
        mContactsList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }
```

All the XML files have been put in place:

contact_list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/text1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:clickable="true"/>
```

contact_list_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

My main activity consists of 2 `FrameLayout`s for the fragments to be put in. This is it's XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_contacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:textColor="#0a20a3" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/frag_contact_details"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textColor="#045011" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the `onCreate` of the activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ninth);
        if (findViewById(R.id.frag_contacts) != null)
        {
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                return;
            ContactsFragment contactsFrag = new ContactsFragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.frag_contacts, contactsFrag).commit();
        }
    }
```

also, this is the `onCreateView` of the fragment:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_list_view, container, false);
    }
```

Now, sorry for the long post, some of it might be unnecessary, but the problem is that on the first snippet, `getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view)` returns null all the time!
Don't know what else to do. how else can I load data into the list, and what is wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: your list is named android.R.id.list ...

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
```

to

```
mContactsList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);
```

Edit:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+idlist"
```

And

```
 mContactsList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but it still does not work.
I am still getting null.

Comment: Thanks Raghunandan, I answered to blackbelt below with the reason why I can't do that

Answer (score 2):

you have to change

```
mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
```

with

```
mContactsList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);
```

Since the ListView belongs to the View you return inside onCreateView.

Comment: Thanks blackbelt, but see my comment to Raghunandan - it did not help.

Comment: @AndroidNewbie you need id `R.id.contacts_list_view` not layout

Comment: @AndroidNewbie of course you have to check for the ListView not for the layout that contains it

Comment: Yes, of course, I was thinking about it too, but this is how it was written in the tutorial. I must have missed something. As you can see in the contact_list_view.xml, I (they) did not define a new id for the ListView. therefore `R.id.contacts_list_view` does not exist in the project.
Is it their mistake, or I had to do something extra? what should I do?
Again, many thanks

Comment: @AndroidNewbie post your layout xml id of listview should be in your fragment xml

Comment: are you extending Fragment or ListFragment? If you are extending ListFragment you can use the getListView() method

Comment: @blackbelt I am extending a Fragment.

Comment: @Raghunandan, what xml should I post exactly? I posted all the xmls

Comment: than you can either try to retrieve your list with id android.R.id.list or change the id of your ListView. @android:id/list is mandatory only if you extend ListActivity or ListFragment

Comment: @AndroidNewbie check my edit as suggested by blackbelt

Comment: @blackbelt it seems to work now! many thanks!
I still don't understand what they were trying to do? what exactly was the difference?

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.layout.contacts_list_view);
```

to

```
mContactsList = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list);
```

contact_list_view.xml shoud be change as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="**@+id/list**"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view) in onCreateView, it will return null, because the View of Fragment is not created yet. Try to do that in onResume and it will return the view:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mContactsList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contacts_list_view);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait till the `Fragment` is attached to the `Activity`. You can do that `onAttach(Activity)` in your `Fragment` class

Answer (score 0):

Fragment state will be saved in FragmentActivity, so you should overwrite onSaveInstanceState in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if(outState != null) {
        String FRAGMENTS_TAG = "android:support:fragments";
        outState.remove(FRAGMENTS_TAG);
    }
}
```